# How to remove child widgets in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, widget

I'm having trouble removing child widgets through kivy. I have tried a few methods (a couple included in my working example). I'm not really sure on the correct way to do this but, I have made a few buttons that appear on my `calc_screen` and on start up I remove them all.

Then later I decide how many of those buttons I need displayed and add them back again.

This method may be completely wrong, but I didn't know another way....

What I am trying to achieve is - When the app starts up, ALL of the buttons that I have made are removed from the `calc_screen` using the `remove_widget()` function. The once the user enters a number, for example 2, I will bring back 2 of the buttons using `add_widget`.

My issue is not being able to remove the buttons on start up, so when the user gets to the `calc_screen` all of the buttons I originally made are there....

I have tried the `children` method along with several other ways to reference the parent widget and the children.

I have included 2 of the methods I tried in the example code. I want `RWY1` and `RWY2` buttons to be removed.

Here is a reproducible example:
Thank you for any and all help. :)

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class CalcScreen(Screen):
    pass

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def on_start(self):
        # method 1
        buttons = self.root.ids['calc_screen'].ids['buttons'].children[0]
        self.root.ids['calc_screen'].remove_widget(buttons)
        # method 2
        RWY1 = self.root.ids['calc_screen'].ids['RWY1']
        self.root.ids['calc_screen'].remove_widget(RWY1)

MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:include calc_screen.kv
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgb: (0,0,0,0)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
        ScreenManager:
            CalcScreen:
                name: "calc_screen"
                id: calc_screen
```

calc_screen.kv

```
<CalcScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: (0,1,0,1)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            id: buttons
            pos_hint: {"top": .9, "center_x": .5}
            size_hint: .8, .08
            Button:
                text: "RWY1"
                id: RWY1
                pos_hint:  {"top": .9, "left": 1}
                size_hint: .3, .08
            Button:
                text: "RWY2"
                id: RWY2
                pos_hint:  {"top": .9, "left": 1}
                size_hint: .3, .08
```

Comment: Would you please clarify the following : *'The once the user enters a number, for example 2... '* ?

Comment: Sorry, yes. So the user can enter a number between 1 and 6. Whatever number they enter, will be the amount of buttons displayed on the calc_screen. So, I will need to re-add the amount of buttons based on their input. Hope that helps

Comment: In case you didn't get it, how and where in your code will the user enter a number ?